# How to detect switch between macOS default & dark mode using Swift 3

Tags: swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter, observers, nsdistributednotification

I want to change my status bar app icon when the user switches from default to dark mode and vice versa (using Swift 3). Here’s what i have so far:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(darkModeChanged(sender:)), name: "AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification", object: nil)
}

...

func darkModeChanged(sender: NSNotification) {
    print("mode changed")
}
```

Unfortunately, it’s not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm using this Swift 3 syntax successfully:

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(interfaceModeChanged(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification"), object: nil)

func interfaceModeChanged(sender: NSNotification) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great solution! :)

Comment: it's not working in Mac catalyst. is there any way to achieve this in Mac catalyst?

Comment: i need objective-c syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 5, Xcode 10.2.1, macOS 10.14.4

Great stuff. My two cents around @Jeffrey's answer:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification = Notification.Name("AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification")
}
```

So one could (instead of `rawValue`):

```
func listenToInterfaceChangesNotification() {
    DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(interfaceModeChanged),
        name: .AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification,
        object: nil
    )
}
```

Remember the `@objc` attribute:

```
@objc func interfaceModeChanged() {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, my little additions as well:

```
enum InterfaceStyle: String {
    case Light
    case Dark
    case Unspecified
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification = Notification.Name("AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification")
}

extension NSViewController {
    var interfaceStyle: InterfaceStyle {
        let type = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AppleInterfaceStyle") ?? "Unspecified"
        return InterfaceStyle(rawValue: type) ?? InterfaceStyle.Unspecified
    }
}
```

and somewhere in a NSViewController:

```
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification,
                                                          object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
            [weak weakSelf = self] (notification) in                // add an observer for a change in interface style
            weakSelf?.setAppearance(toStyle: weakSelf!.interfaceStyle)
        }
```

where `setAppearance` reacts on the change of style.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to update icon images for dark mode, you can do this without notifications by creating a dynamic image that updates automatically.

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances):

> To create an image that draws its content dynamically, use the [`init(size:flipped:drawingHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519860-init) method to initialize your image with a custom drawing handler block. AppKit calls your handler block whenever the system appearance changes, giving you a chance to redraw the image using the new appearance.