# How to change UIColor according to UserInterfaceStyle(Dark Mode/Light Mode) in UIView extension in swift [5+]?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicolor, ios-darkmode

I was creating the method in ***UIView extension*** and I needed to **change UIColor according to UIUserInterfaceStyle** *i.e. separate UIColor for both Dark & Light mode Interface.*

> Usually, in `UIViewController` class `traitCollectionDidChange` method
> is triggered whenever UIUserInterfaceStyle is changed and we can
> determine the current user interface style by

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.changeUIWithUserInterface(style: self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle)
    }
}
```

***But the Extension of UIView does not have traitCollectionDidChange method that can be triggered***

so how can I change the UIColor according to UIUserInterfaceStyle in UIView extension?
I figured it out and thought to post it for fellow devs.

*Hope It Helps :)*

Comment: Why are you using a DispatchQueue for UI-Work? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: changeUIWithUserInterface method changes UI whenever it's called, that's why i put it in DispatchQueue.main.., am i missing something here, @baronfac

Comment: Yes. It will always be called on the main thread

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below method works like a charm for me!
It is triggered whenever `traitCollection` changes..
  It can work on any extension of various UI components

```
UIColor.init { (trait) -> UIColor in
    return trait.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? darkModeColor : lightModeColor
}
```

> You have to check for iOS 13+, if you are working with support of iOS versions below 13, which you can check easily

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    //Dark mode is supported 
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.init { (trait) -> UIColor in
        return trait.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? darkModeColor : lightModeColor
    }
} else {
    //Earlier version of iOS, which does not suppport dark mode.
    self.backgroundColor = lightModeColor
}
```

Reference: [Thanks to answer of @ElanoVasconcelos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646380/12456741)

Answer (score 1):

You can **set UIColor as simple variable**, that automatically changes when `traitCollection` changes:

```
struct ColorPalette {

public static var subtitleColor: UIColor = {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        return UIColor { (UITraitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
            if UITraitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
                return UIColor.lightText
            } else {
                return .darkGray
            }
        }
    } else {
        /// Return a fallback color for iOS 12 and lower.
        return .darkGray
    }
  }()
}
```

Usage:

```
label.textColor = ColorPalette.subtitleColor
```

Comment: Yes sir, you are right but that's the next step, my problem was that i can not change color in method that is created in extension of UIView... you are also using the same thing (UIColor's init method with traitcollection )..which i did not know about...so thought that might help a fellow..anyways thanks for sharing!